# Getting "could not resolve ... from state ..." error when using nested routes angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm new to angularjs and I want to use nested ui-routes for my application. Some code snippets ...

profile.html

```
<div class="row">
<div class="dl-horizontal" id="information">

    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

    <!-- edit button -->
    <div style="margin-bottom: 15px">   
        <div class="button" style="margin-top:5px" style="float:left">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ui-sref="edit_profile" ng-click="populate()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit Profile</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

client_UI.js

```
//object for routing
var route = angular.module('route', ["ui.router"])

// configure the routing        
route.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

    // send to profile page
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/profile");

    $stateProvider

    // route for personal info
    .state('profile', {
        url: "/profile", 
        templateUrl : "profile_area/profile.html" , 
        controller : 'profileController'
    })
```

edit.html

```
<script src="Scripts/angular-ui-bootstrap.js"></script>


    <!-- title -->
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h2 class="modal-title"> Editing Profile</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form" id="myForm">

            <!-- Name -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name &nbsp;</label>
                <input placeholder="{{infos.Name}}" id="name" type="text" ng-model="name">
            </div>
```

profile.js

```
//object for routing
var route = angular.module('route', ["ui.router"])

// configure the routing        
route.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

$stateProvider

//route for edit page
.state('edit_profile', {
    url: "/edit_profile",
    templateURL : "edit/edit_profile.html" ,
    controller : 'editController'
})
});

route.controller('editController' ["$scope", "$resource", function($scope, $resource) {

// resource objects
var profile = $resource($scope.apicall + "/api/userprofile/", {Userid:$scope.userid}, {'post':{method: 'POST'}});
var edit = new profile();
```

and this is the view (index.html) ...

```
       <!-- route veiw -->
    <div class="container" id="route" style="width:90%">
            <div ui-view></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer></footer>
```

I'm getting an error from the console that says, Could not resolve "'edit_profile' from state 'profile'" and edit.html is supposed to be the child state of profile.html. I'm using ui-routing in angularjs. I want to be able to click a button in the profile.html that will change the state to edit_profile and will be displayed in the ui-view in index.html. Any suggestions on how to fix this or is there another easy way to do this?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In this case, angular is informing us: *I simply cannot find the state `edit_profile`*. I created working [example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/oFgHu1FPB0LyRQmgE0xC?p=preview)

The reason is in fact, that we really have to load 2 js files:

- profile.js
- client_UI.js

both of them **must be loaded** but both of them **cannot** declare the same module:

```
var route = angular.module('route', ["ui.router"])
```

one of them must be different or just not declare but consume the module:

```
// client_UI.js
var route = angular.module('client_ui', ["ui.router"])
// profile.js
var route = angular.module('route', ["ui.router", "client_ui"])
```

or both could be in same module:

```
// client_UI.js
var route = angular.module('route', ["ui.router"])
// profile.js
var route = angular.module('route')
```

Check that all working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/oFgHu1FPB0LyRQmgE0xC?p=preview)

Comment: ... Is there a reason for a **down** vote? It would be nice to know that... to be able to extend or improve the answer....

Comment: Yes, "must be loaded" was the key for me.  My state had not been resolved yet, hence it had not been loaded.

Comment: I'm new to angular and confused by your answer, could you please tell us Why we need both, I assume 1 create and1 consume is so duplicate objects don't get created, but why both?

Comment: @EricBrown-Cal you should read basics about angular. It is real BASIC stuff, how modules do work in AngularJS. Start e.g. here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module and if you have still questions, do [ASK here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: why u guys use plunkr for example it never opens