# Injection Error Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependencies, code-injection

I'm trying to dependency inject a service and I'm getting the following error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: allStatesServiceProvider <- allStatesService

Script: `PlanDesignController`

```
(function () {
   'use strict';
   var controllerId = 'PlanDesignController';

   angular.module('myApp').controller(controllerId, 
        ['$scope', 'planDesignService', 'allStatesService', 
        'logger', '$timeout', '$routeParams', '$location', PlanDesignController]);

   function PlanDesignController($scope, planDesignService, allStatesService
                            , logger, $timeout, $routeParams, $location) { }
}
```

Script: `allStatesService`

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  var serviceId = 'allStatesService';

  angular.module('myApp')
   .factory(serviceId, ['$http','logger', 'appSettings', 'breeze', allStatesService]);

  console.log("Gets into AllStatesService.js");

  function allStatesService($http, logger, appSettings) {}
}
```

What can I do to resolve this error?

Comment: Why you are injecting controller and your service as a dependency?

Comment: I'm not sure if your English is just bad but i'm assuming you're asking why i'm injecting a service into my controller? What this allows me to do is have access to the methods/members/properties/etc. of that "injected" service within the controller that i "injected" it into.  Does that help to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

I am not fully sure where is the issue here. So I created a plunker to show that your code is almost working. Check this [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/jV5MHQag7aQtvRTbvB9F?p=preview). A bit adjusted code snippet

```
angular.module('myApp', []); 

(function () {
  'use strict';
  var controllerId = 'PlanDesignController';

  angular.module('myApp').controller(controllerId, 
    ['$scope', 'planDesignService', 'allStatesService', 
     'logger', '$timeout', '$routeParams', '$location', PlanDesignController]);

    function PlanDesignController($scope, planDesignService, allStatesService
    , logger, $timeout, $routeParams, $location)
    { $scope.text = allStatesService.greet()}

})();

(function () {
  'use strict';
  var serviceId = 'allStatesService';

  angular.module('myApp')
    .factory(serviceId, ['$http', 'logger', 'appSettings', 'breeze'
    , allStatesService]);

 function allStatesService($http, logger, appSettings) {
   var greeting = function() {
     return "Welcome from service"
   };
   return {
     greet : greeting,
   };
 }

})();
```

The main change now is that service returns object with a funtcion called **`greet()`**. This is called in controller and its result is placed into the scope.

This code snippet shows, that it is almost the same... but [working](http://plnkr.co/edit/jV5MHQag7aQtvRTbvB9F?p=preview). So that could help you to find out what is different in your original code... and make it running

Comment: This code didn't work for me. Actually, i didn't see any changes to the dependency injection and the Plunkr only tests the controller, not the service. The service is the issue, my controller works fine.

Comment: I updated plunker and answer. Now you should see, that service is used to provide some functionality and its result is displayed via controller... does it help anyhow?

Comment: Okay, this looks good but i can't tell if there is a difference between what you have and what i have...I'm doing the injection in an identical way, which is making this frustrating since i can't see why i should get that error!

Comment: I would expect, that there will be some ... hidden difference. E.g. different **.module()** - For example, Controller goes to `angular.module('myAppCtrls')`, while service is in `angular.module('myAppSrvc')` ... if this happens, you **must be sure**, that one module does load the other **`module('myAppCtrls', ['myAppSrvc'...])`** this would by my suspected... Detailed explanation of that issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24902567/1679310

Comment: Okay, it was an issue w/ my service. I wasn't injecting like i should. I changed it to:
myApp.service('allStatesService', function ($http, $log, logger, appSettings, breeze) {

Comment: Great to see that ;) Enjoy Angular JS ;)