# Dynamic links and "could not resolve from state" error in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying give dynamic link from my models which names are "aracData.planlama".

There is no problem on this. But when I click the link I get "could not resolve from state" error on console.

```
 <div class="form-group">
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="aracData.planlama" value="sifirmi">
        Araç satın alınmış durumda
    </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="aracData.planlama" value="satin-alinacak">
        Satın alınması planlanıyor
    </label>
</div>
```

```
<div class="form-group row">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
    <a ui-sref="form.{{aracData.planlama}}" class="btn btn-block btn-info" ng-class="{disabled:aracData.planlama == undefined}">
        Sonraki adım <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**And theese are my routing codes:**

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider

    .state('form', {
        url: '/form',
        templateUrl: 'form.html',
        controller: 'formController'
    })
    .state('form.profile', {
        url: '/profile',
        templateUrl: 'form-profile.html'
    })
    .state('form.interests', {
        url: '/interests',
        templateUrl: 'form-interests.html'
    })
    .state('form.sifirmi', {
        url: '/sifirmi',
        templateUrl: 'sifir-mi-ikinci-el-mi.html'
    })
    .state('form.alindimi', {
        url: '/alindimi',
        templateUrl: 'alindi-mi.html'
    })
    .state('form.payment', {
        url: '/payment',
        templateUrl: 'form-payment.html'
    });
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/form/profile');
```

})

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you paste the full error ?

Comment: Error: Could not resolve 'form.' from state 'form.alindimi'
    at Object.v.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.min.js:7)
    at Object.v.go (angular-ui-router.min.js:7)
    at angular-ui-router.min.js:7
    at angular.js:14014
    at e (angular.js:4300)
    at angular.js:4601

Comment: This might be of help to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895163/getting-could-not-resolve-from-state-error-when-using-nested-routes-an

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass an expression to `ui-sref` for the state name. Instead, you can do this in the controller.

```
<a ng-click="go(aracData.planlama)">
```

Inject the `$state` service into your controller, then do:

```
$scope.go = function(sub) {
  $state.go('form.'+sub);
};
```

This will probably also work:

```
$scope.go = $state.go; // may need to do $state.go.bind($state);

<a ng-click="go('form'+aracData.planlama)">
```

[Click here for GitHub discussion about dynamic state name for ui-sref.](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/395)

Comment: I fixed it by using href insead of ui-sref. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @BasarSen I wouldn't use the url directly like that. It's best practice to change states rather than urls. Hardcoded urls will make maintenance more difficult (i.e. if you change the state's url later)

Comment: I changed it again into your answer. Thank you four your advice.