# Could not resolve from state 'app'

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I know that this has been asked before ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265230/could-not-resolve-from-state) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24895163/getting-could-not-resolve-from-state-error-when-using-nested-routes-an) among others), but I just can't understand what is the problem with my code. Here it is:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
angular
    .module('app.students', ['common', 'xeditable', "googlechart", 'iosDblclick', 'anguFixedHeaderTable', 'disableAll'])
    .config(config);

/** @ngInject */
function config($stateProvider, $translatePartialLoaderProvider) {
    // State
    $stateProvider
        .state('app.students', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/students'
        })

        .state('app.students.studentList', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'content@app': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/main/students/views/studentList/studentList.html',
                    controller: 'StudentListController as vm'
                }
            }
        })

        .state('app.studentsInProcess.studentList', {
            url: '/process/:id',
            views: {
                'content@app': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/main/students/views/studentList/studentList.html',
                    controller: 'StudentListController as vm'
                }
            },
            parent: 'app.students'
        })

        .state('app.students.studentDetails', {
            url: '/:id',
            views: {
                'content@app': {
                    templateUrl: 'app/main/students/views/studentDetails/studentDetails.html',
                    controller: 'StudentDetailsController as vm'
                }
            }

        });

    // Translation
    $translatePartialLoaderProvider.addPart('app/main/students');
}
})();
```

When I click on a link with a ui-sref of "app.studentsInProcess.studentList" i Get the error
"Error: Could not resolve 'app.studentsInProcess.studentList' from state 'app'"
What am I doing wrong? Please bear with me as this stuff is new to me.

Comment: pretty sure it is because `.state('app.studentsInProcess')` does not exist

Comment: But I'm telling it that its parent is 'app.students'. Doesn't it help it resolve the state?

Comment: When you name as state as 'app.studentsInProcess.studentList' it implies that 'app.studentsInProcess' is the parent.  However you are also specifying `parent:` explicitly.  This might be an invalid state.  Try naming your state something like `studentsInProcess` (no dots) and see if that works

Comment: Also I suggest adding a passthrough template in your `app.students` state so you don't have to use named view targetting in ALL nested states.  `{ abstract: true, url: '/students', views: { content: { template: '<ui-view></ui-view>' } } }`